# Can setrlimit be used to put limitations on firefox?

Tags: linux, macos, firefox, memory, c++

I noticed that firefox sometimes uses a lot of memory. Can something like setrlimit be used to control it? I tried to use it on the command line, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea.  If Firefox reaches the memory limit, it may crash instead of continuing to run with no new tabs or other content (the behavior you appear to be expecting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various shells support `setrlimit(2,3p)`, such as bash via `ulimit`. See `help ulimit` for more details.